# simplest possible way to prove chain rule for second derivative

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Given $\phi=\phi(u)$ and $u=u(x)$

What is the simplest possible way to prove
$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}=\bigg(\frac{du}{dx}\bigg)^2.\frac{d^2\phi}{du^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}.\frac{d\phi}{du}
$$

Comment: by proving that $\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$, which is easily achieved by writing the equivalent definition of the derivative at $x_0$ : $f(x) = f(x_0) + (x-x_0) f'(x_0) + (x-x_0) h(x)$ where $h(x) \to 0$ when $x \to x_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by repeated application of the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\big(\frac{d\phi}{dx}\big)=\frac{d}{dx}\big(\frac{d\phi}{du}\frac{du}{dx}\big)=\frac{d}{dx}\big(\frac{d\phi}{du}\big)\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{d\phi}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d}{du}\big(\frac{d\phi}{du}\big)\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{d\phi}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2\phi}{du^2}\big(\frac{du}{dx}\big)^2+\frac{d\phi}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}
$$

where $\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d}{du}$

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried just iterating the chain rule for the first derivative? It's the first thing that comes to mind and a simple computation does the trick.

Hope that helps,